# Cant click div with links behind another div Absolute Position wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div behind another div with html links. The problem is this div is in a jquery made content slider. And because of this i cant click the links on the div thats underneath. Is there a way i can make it clickable. I tried `position:absolute` but it did not work. Maybe there is a jquery hack or something?

The div that blocks my navigation div is called "maincontent" and the navigation div is called "nav" the problem is the maincontent div is over the "nav" div because i used `margin-top: -60px;` due to how i needed to code it.

Comment: Wow, kindly demarcate the DIV with clear id names in your question, it's confusing which DIV is what.

Comment: Well one div is a large div called "maincontent" and the div under it is called "nav" but links dont work on it/

Comment: Can you please add those names in parantheses near the words 'div' repeated throughout the question?

Comment: Comment here so that I get pinged, once done :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to the nav bar. Didn't do it? It's because maincontent has a `z-index` set on it. Add one too to the nav block and make sure it's higher than the one set on maincontent. That's it I guess.

Comment: Nope it doesnt maybe cause its a content slider using jquery?

Comment: I don't think so. Can you post the both the html and the css for this little part? It'd be easier to understand the problem. Make a small fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Its actually alot ill link you here via a shortened url here.

Comment: Basically the navigation on the bottom footer you will see i cant click it.

Comment: Try adding `position:relative` again to the nav. That's all I did and it started working. Wait, add it to the footer - that way the whole footer becomes click/selectable - as I guess you want it.

Comment: Let me try it hold on a second.

Comment: Yeah it worked perfectly but now the iphone image went behind the footer i want it over.

Comment: Ya. `position: relative;` and `z-index: 1;` you need the position relative  for z-index to take effect.

Comment: z index 1 didnt seem to kick it

Comment: For some reason its still under the footer i tried a higher value as well.

Comment: What element did you add it to? I've added it to the img and it seems to be working for me :) It comes on top of the footer, its bottom overlaps it a little.

Comment: Let me try adding it to the image

Comment: Its not working for me can you maybe post the code you used? I tried `z-index: 1:` on the css for `#intro-right` and the image style.

Comment: `position:relative; z-index: 1;` you need the position relative there otherwise z-index does nothing ;)

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Now i know that i need position:. Question though what does the position relative do exactly?

Comment: I'll gladly explain it to you, but I just can't do it now. It's 5:40 am where I'm at and my body - guess what - is asking for some sleep. Got home at 5:00, prepared something to eat, opened my laptop to quickly check my email and here I am at five, forty.... five, forty four. If you come back here tomorrow evening I'll have an answer prepared for you. ;) sorry. Position relative does a few things so it could take a while to write a proper answer.

Comment: Haha alright :) Thanks so much for your help though. I appreciate it, ill definitely do my own research though.

Comment: The problem with z-index > 0 starts causing other issues with overlappings

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that making `nav` appear over `maincontent` will not cause any visual problems (like nav obstructing some content of maincontent) - then you can try using the CSS property `z-index` on both these DIVs, and setting the `z-index` of `nav` to be higher (like 100) than the `z-index` of `maincontent` (maybe 50 - the numbers are totally arbitrary, just check if there are any other elements with `z-index` settings in your layout and don't clash with those).

Of course, beware of the horrid IE, it has some weird issues with relative (or was that absolute?) positioning and z-index.

Comment: absolute wont work cause its in a sliding content. I will try zindex though

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't suggesting using absolute either, I was simply saying if you at all use absolute, be aware of IE's bugs.

Comment: How do you start a chat here?

Comment: You can visit http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ for chat, and yes, posting your URL would certainly help. Z-Index almost never works on the first try, you must tough it out... use firebug to help along the way.

Comment: Ive tried zindex before it always worked for me but not in this case for some reason.

Comment: Do both DIVs have the position property set? It's important for z-index to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

My problem was that if I changed the z-index to >0 then the problems with breaking design came up.

Since my page had static elements I made the buttons fit into their positions  but without them being in the container with the other elements.

I had:

```
.container#body-container

    #menu-buttons
        .menu-item#One
        .menu-item#Two
        .menu-item#Three
        .menu-item#Four
        .menu-item#Five
```

when things began breaking up so I changed it to

```
#nav-menu-container
    #One
    #Two
    #Three
    #Four
    #Five


.container#body-container

    #menu-buttons
        .menu-item
        .menu-item
        .menu-item
        .menu-item
        .menu-item
```

I know it's a bit hacky but this is the best I got so far.